# Python, csv writer function

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I created a csv function that should ask for a file path and for X number of strings to write to the file with an specified csv delimiter.

```
def WRITE_csv(csv_path,*args):
    with open(csv_path, "ab") as f:
        csv_list=csv.writer(f,delimiter='|')

        csv_string=""
        for arg in args:
            csv_string=csv_string+","+arg

        csv_string=csv_string[1:]

        csv_list.writerow([csv_string])
```

The problem is that the csv module is writing `,` instead of `|`

---

As a bonnus, I wanted to replace:

```
        csv_string=""
        for arg in args:
            csv_string=csv_string+","+arg
```

With a one-line function

`csv_string="".format(','.join(arg for arg in args))`

but it always giving me an empty string!

Comment: @Jongware: yet the `delimiter` argument lets you specify your own delimiter. Provided you actually *use more than one column*...

Comment: @Jongware This is why we can specify a delimiter..

Comment: @rsm: but why are you then joining the `args` into a single string with commas? You appear to misunderstand how the writer works, you pass in a *sequence of columns*, not one string.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters i was wrinting a single string with commas because i noticed that when i write using writerow, i have to use the following format `csv_list.writerow([string1,string2,string3,ect..])`

Comment: that's because you are then building a new list object. The `,` commas are *not string values*, they are Python syntax to delimit the different elements that you are asking Python to put into the list.

Comment: Your `args` here is *already a suitable sequence*. You don't need to make it into a new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the **literal** `,` string in your value for the delimiter.  You are writing just **one column**:

```
csv_list.writerow([csv_string])
```

so the `csv.writer()` never has cause to put the `|` delimiter in, as there is no second column to delimit. You passed in one whole string, `csv_string`, as a one-value list, so naturally that is seen as the only column. The module does *not* split the string on commas again.

Leave putting in the delimiter to the writer instead:

```
def WRITE_csv(csv_path, *args):
    with open(csv_path, "ab") as f:
        csv_list=csv.writer(f,delimiter='|')    
        csv_list.writerow(args)
```

In other words, `args` is *already the right type* for the `csv.writerow()` call, you don't need to convert it here.